Why is my dynamic drive so slow?
I use an old PC as a backup file server, and recently installed additional drives to try to extend its life.  (I freely admit, I'm a cheap bastard, and fully realize that this is not a normal way to create a file server.)  In addition, the machine's SATA interface has a limit of 2TB per drive, which I'd been working around for a while - so after installing the new drives, I configured them as a single pooled ("Dynamic") disk.  (This is essentially a backup to my backups, and so doesn't use any RAID features.)  However, this setup seems unworkably slow - I tasked the machine to move a large folder of large files to the new disks, and it's been chugging at it for more than 48 hours now, but it's nowhere near completion.  Internet searches have so far turned up only one page that even mentions the problem, but seems to only confirm that my problem isn't the one they're talking about there.  Here's the output from the two commands mentioned there:
  Disk ###  Status      Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  ----------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online       466 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online      1863 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online      1863 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online      1863 GB      0 B   *
  Disk 4    Online      1863 GB      0 B   *

BlockSize  Index  Name                   StartingOffset
512        0      Disk #0, Partition #0  32256
512        1      Disk #0, Partition #1  40048887808
512        0      Disk #1, Partition #0  32256
512        0      Disk #2, Partition #0  32256
512        0      Disk #3, Partition #0  32256
512        0      Disk #4, Partition #0  32256

Am I interpreting this output correctly, that the dynamic drives are already correctly configured?  If so, does anyone have a suggestion of where else to look for the bottleneck?

I've heard of Windows dynamic disks being slow in general (does the OS version not support Storage Spaces?), but what's the controller model out of curiosity? It wouldn't be one of those trash ones that only have a single queue for all disks, would it?

This is the controller; I don't how good it is objectively, but I wouldn't be surprised if the problem boiled down to my cheapskate tendencies from many years ago coming back to bite me in the butt.
